# Spring bean messageSouce cannot be in ApplicationConfig and WebMvcConfig at the same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to put the @Bean `SpringTemplateEngine` in the `ApplicationConfig` so that I can @Autowire it into a @Component that generates emails. (See [Thymeleaf-Spring4 unable to autowire TemplateEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977449/thymeleaf-spring4-unable-to-autowire-templateengine) and [Rich HTML email in Spring with Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/springmail.html)). Therefore the @Bean(name = "messageSource") needs to be in the `ApplicationConfig` as well. However, I have a `WebMvcConfig` that extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and the method `@Override Validator getValidator()` needs to `setValidationMessageSource` with messageSource(). However, since I moved it to the `ApplicationConfig` I don't know how to get at it from `WebMvcConfig`. I started with [spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) from [kolorobot](https://github.com/kolorobot). Instead of finding a whole new configuration archetype, maybe someone here can point me in a helpful direction.

Relevant Code for `ApplicationConfig`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class, excludeFilters = @Filter ({Controller.class, Configuration.class}))
class ApplicationConfig {
*** Incomplete Example ***
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename(MESSAGE_SOURCE);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    Set<TemplateResolver> resolvers = new HashSet<TemplateResolver>();
    resolvers.add(classLoaderTemplateResolver());
    resolvers.add(mvcTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolvers(resolvers);
    templateEngine.setMessageSource(messageSource());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}
}
```

And Relevant Code for `WebMvcConfig`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class}, includeFilters = @Filter (Controller.class), useDefaultFilters = false)
class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {    
*** Incomplete Example ***
@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return validator;
}
}
```

The issue seems to be that I cannot move the getValidator() to the ApplicationConfig() because it must override the WebMvcConfigurationSupport method.

Comment: Why not @Autowired MessageSource in your WebMvcConfig?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can Autowire things in the Configuration portion. I would bet against it actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by creating two separate SpringTemplateEngine configurations, one in the MvcWebConfig for view rendering and one in ApplicationConfig for handling emails. I put the email messages in a separate file and called setTemplateEngineMessageSource instead of setMessageSource as per documentation.